# Vue js application object syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started to learn the vue.js and came across this syntax. I want to know what this syntax is called.

```
const CounterApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++
    }, 1000)
  }
}
Vue.createApp(Counter).mount('#counter')
```

Can anyone explain if `data` and `mounted` are properties of object or methods because never seen this type of syntax of object literal in js. Usually they have `:` between value and key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a short way writing for `methods` declaration inside `object` introduced in `ES6`

```
 data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
```

is equals to

```
data: function() {
  return {
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this syntax called `Enhanced Object Literals` it is a new feature from the new features in ES6 or they called it to ECMA Script 2015

and in the old syntax, you could write it like this

```
const CounterApp = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++
    }, 1000)
  }
}
Vue.createApp(Counter).mount('#counter')
```

you can read more about [Enhanced Object Literals](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/enhanced-object-literals-in-es6-a9d) here.
this article is fine to check the new features of [ES6](https://webapplog.com/es6/)